# NoClassDefFoundError when trying to send sms to mobile from way2sms.com using htmlunit

Tags: java

I'm getting `NoClassDefFoundError`,

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;

public class abc
{
    public static void main() throws Exception
    {
        WebClient webClient=new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://site21.way2sms.com/main.action?section=s&Token=30A947B31996468484EC0FE6647B6A58.w808&vfType=register_verify");
        page.executeJavaScript("loadSMSPage('sendSMS')");
        webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        HtmlInput num1=page.getElementByName("mobile");
        num1.setValueAttribute(t2.getText());
        HtmlInput num2=page.getElementByName("message");
        num2.setValueAttribute(q);
        HtmlSubmitInput butt=page.getElementByName("send");
        page=butt.click();
    }
}
```

The above code is throwing exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/DecoderException`

Comment: You need commons-codec.jar on the classpath.

Comment: Hey Vivek! Just for future reference, it would be nice if you could format your code a bit nicer. It isn't indented at all, making it hard to read. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask